# Find latest date from a list until first column changes

Tags: excel, date

I have a 3 column list - the first contains pathnames or "#N/A" (as an error) and the second is a list of dates. In the third column I want the latest date from the second column to be picked from the list of dates before the next pathname appears. Can anyone help identify an Excel formula to achieve this? An example of a correctly populated third column is below. Many thanks.

***Example:***

[image]

Comment: If you use a helping column (Extra column for tricks), then it would be easy to do that. If you interested then share a sample file. I will be able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the fact that all the pathnames start with \\ and use something like this starting in C2

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,2)="\\",MAX(B2:INDEX(B3:B10,MATCH("\\*",A3:A10,0)-1)),"")
```

adjusting B10 and A10 to how far forward you want to look in the list of dates (I just find it easier to test things with a small range).

Please note that you will need to insert a dummy \\ after the last row to make it work for the last set of dates.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Tom Sharpe - that solves it in a single column, +1 from me. I've just solved it myself simultaneously by inserting a column to get rid of the "#N/A"s first (sorry these were actual #N/As not just text) - and used the formula: =IF(ISNA(A1),C1,A1) and extending down. In column D - I then used the formula: =MAX(IF((C1:C$1000000=A1),B1:B$1000000)) - I started with 10 like you but as my xls is about a million rows I had to extend this eventually.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, either way does the job.